# iOS Safari - position elements off the viewport

Tags: iphone, ios, css, ios6

I'm wondering if it's possible to position elements with `position: absolute;` outside the viewport in iOS6.

Even when I use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, maximum-scale=0.5, initial-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5" />` it makes viewport have more width if an element is positioned with like `right: 0; margin-right: -100px;` (100px out of the viewport).

iOS tries to include this element in the viewport which is not what I want. I want to have it partially visible and partially hidden. And iOS adds horizontal scrollbar and includes the part of an element which is supposed to be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, if you use a wrapper with **`overflow: hidden`**

This example shows a red rectangle 100x100px that is position 50px to right of the viewport, without the viewport including it.

Create a container **`#limit`** that is aligned to the right of the viewport. Prevent to contents from enlarging the viewport by setting the overflow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #limit {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #offset {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                right: -50px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background: #f00;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="limit">
            <div id="offset">
                Hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```